# How can I have a jQuery Sortable element not just drop around other sortable elements, but on top of other elements itself as well?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

For example, I have images in a sortable list, and I would like arrange them. However, I would also like the ability to stack them rather than just arranging the order. How can I do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Sortable items are always avoiding to be overlapped by design. Before starting development, it's a good idea to have some pen and paper and think about your desired user interaction, and try to see if it would work at all before putting hours into implementation. Once you've got a clear idea and concept, you can share it with us and we'll see if we can help.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, simple have the z-index of the sortable below that of the non-dragged elements. Then bind a mouseover event on the elements that needs to be hovered for your custom actions. So because the z-index of the non-dragged items is higher, the mouseover event will always be triggered. So, hover events on sorting draggables :)